# Tensorflow - Custom model training in addition to existing one in

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I did follow this nice tutorial
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

It works pretty fine, but my goal is to ADD new class to existing inception Coco model, so for instance I will still be capable to detect people, cars, etc + custom models.
Is there a specif section in the class? or setting I should apply before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to retrain with training data consisting of all 90 classes + the new classes you are interested in. As retraining overwrites previous trained classes knowledge/ability on the final layers. Or just have two models one for the 90 classes and one for the new object that you trained on

Comment: Thx, If I use 2 model same time, how can I detect output object on same image/video? is there any set of sample code? thx